# Does Facebook Messenger automatically mark messages as seen after a while?

Tags: facebook, facebook-messenger

If a person hasn't read a message on Messenger within a certain number of days, does it just automatically get marked as seen?

A person didn't respond to my message (I don't think it needed a response anyway but still). It was shown as "delivered" but not "seen". After a few days it was shown as "seen". It happened with two people.

Do you think they actually clicked on the message and read it or does Facebook mark it as "seen" after a while even if they didn't click on the message?

Answer (score 2):

I doubt that's the case, it doesn't mark them as read automatically. They might have opened it my mistake or they might be plain lying to you

Answer (score 1):

**No**, Facebook doesn't mark messages as seen until recipient has not seen it. I am sure they have read it. Once a message has opened then only it get marked as seen.

In your case, may be they have opened the message(s) and thought to not reply or may be they have open but didn't care about it or may be they are lying to you.

Comment: If you wanted me to use more formal language, you could have just edited my answer :)

Comment: @KaranShah: I want you to learn it from yourself. :)

Comment: Hehe :) sure I will

Answer (score 0):

It's possible they just marked all their unread messages as "read". That will show as "seen" on your account but is no guarantee that they actually opened it or read it.
It's also possible they did open it and read it. Facebook doesn't automatically mark messages as "seen".